# Git store binary files to an external folder on commit and recovers on checkout?

Tags: git, binaryfiles

1. Is there a way to configure git so that whenever a file `~/repoA/**/*.png` is commited, a unique hash X of it is calucated, a file `~/repoA.data/X` is copied from `~/repoA/**/*.png`, and a file `./**/*.png` containing X is stored in the git?
2. Reversely, is there a way to configure git so that whenever a file `./**/*.png` is checked out, it's content X is retrieved and the corresponding file `~/repoA.data/X` is copied to `<working directory>/**/*.png`?
3. Similar to 2, to configure git so that whenever the content X of `./**/*.png` is to be outputted, output the content of corresponding file `~/repoA.data/X`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand the question correctly. But if you're looking for a smart way to let handle binary files with git, you probably wanna take a look at these  projects:
http://git-annex.branchable.com/
https://github.com/schacon/git-media